# Can you help me removing index.php in Rewrite Rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's my code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/$ index.index?pm=$1 [L]
```

It doesnt work using this link:

```
http://localhost/display/1001
```

but it does when you add ? before the number

```
http://localhost/display/?1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, you did not provide enough information about your actual situation and what you are trying to achieve. So we have to do a bit of *guess work* here and hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?display/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?pm=$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).